# Validation rules for controller retrieved from business layer

Tags: laravel, validation, n-tier-architecture, laravel-5.4

When building controllers, is it bad practice to have the validation rules come from the injected repository? As an example, consider the following interface:

```
interface UserRepository
{
  /**
   * @return array
   */
  public function getCreateRules();
}
```

Then the usage of this function would be found in the controller's `store` method:

```
class UserController extends Controller 
{
    private $repo;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repo) 
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, $this->repo->getCreateRules());

        ...
    }
}
```

My question is if by moving the rules to the business layer that it is mixing concerns. The idea came from [this](https://medium.com/laravel-5-tutorials/practical-versioning-c56886ee1349#.dji409w0q) Medium post from 2014 so I am wondering if that is a valid resource given its age.

Comment: Have you got any conditional logic in the repository for what rules should be sent back?

Comment: No conditional logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally not use a repository for this and instead use a `FormRequest`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation

This way:

1. you're code is still reusable
2. you don't have to create any addition logic as it's all built-in
3. You can use type hinting to resolve the class out of the container which will in turn run automatically handle the validation on the method.

Also, if you need your rules to be different for create and update you can use a simple switch statement e.g.

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'GET':
            return [
                //Create rules
            ];
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
            return [
                //Update rules
            ];
    }
}
```

You `store` method would then look something like:

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    //Validation will have already been handled by this point so you
    //don't need to add it manually
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is fantastic. I didn't know that those existed. Thank you.